# Kubernetes - Network policy for communication between services

Tags: kubernetes

I need help on Network policy for the below requirement.

Is it possible to let Application A in namespace A connect to only Application B in namespace B?  I want only one application from one namespace to connect to only one application on another namespace?

I have a network policy at global for default deny all.

Currently, there is only OR for network policy. What I am looking for is AND so that I can say, allow namespace A & pod A. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#behavior-of-to-and-from-selectors. It allows you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. For an ingress network policy, you just have to set both `namespaceSelector` and `podSelector` in the `from` section to specify both the namespace and pod labels (of application A and namespace A, in your example) -- the selectors are ANDed together. For the target, use the `podSelector` field to select application B, and make sure the `namespace` in the network policy metadata is set to namespace B.

Note that to use `namespaceSelector`, you will have to label your namespace. Namespaces are not labeled in Kubernetes by default.

Check out the Across Namespaces section in [this guide](https://www.stackrox.com/post/2019/04/setting-up-kubernetes-network-policies-a-detailed-guide/) for a more thorough explanation, and an example YAML.

Answer (score -1):

Pods can communicate with each other across the namespaces:

App 1 in namespace 1:

```
$ kubectl -n namespace1 get po -o wide
NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
app1-5d8bb8ffbb-7x74v                       1/1       Running   0          1d        10.233.65.115   node1.example.kz
```

App 2 in namespace 2:

```
$ kubectl -n namespace2 get po -o wide
NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
app2-569f46b8d5-fz9dw                       1/1       Running   0          1d        10.233.67.80    node2.example.kz
```

I can connect to the App 2 from the App 1:

```
kubectl -n namespace1 exec app1-5d8bb8ffbb-7x74v -- ping -c 1 10.233.67.80
PING 10.233.67.80 (10.233.67.80) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.233.67.80: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.917 ms

--- 10.233.67.80 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.917/0.917/0.917/0.000 ms
```

This example is very simple. Depending on kind of connection and your apps configuration, you might need `Service`, `Ingress` resources

More info:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Also, this documentation will be helpful:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#kubernetes-model

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain clearly. We have global deny all and hence looking for network

Answer (score -1):

How groups of pods are allowed to communicate with each other and other network endpoints is configured with `NetworkPolicy` resource.
Your networking solution (CNI plugin) has to support NetworkPolicy, because you need a controller. Simply creating the resource without a controller to implement it will have no effect.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

Take a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/ for more examples.

Comment: I need help on Network policy and just update my question to make it clear.